# Need some ideas how to make delete (BooleanField) in Django

Tags: python, database, django

I'm trying to do this: in my web site, I have some data from database, like this:

```
Math 140
Math 141
CS 320
CS 240
```

And I want to do it like this: When you check box and than press delete, this subject gets deleted from database.

```
Math 140 []
Math 141 []
CS 320 []
CS 240 []
```

template.html

```
    <div id="subjects-list">
        {% if user.username %}
            <ul>
                {% if subjects %}
                    {% for subject in subjects %}
                        <li>{{ subject.name }} 
                    {% endfor %}
                {% else %}
                No Subjects for this user
                {% endif %}
            </ul>
        {% else %}
                You are in else
        {% endif %}
    </div>
```

models.py

```
class Subjects(models.Model):
    """ Subject Database """
    name = models.CharField(max_length=64, unique=False) #Subject Names on left-menu 
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, unique=False)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return '%s %s' %(self.name, self.user.username)
```

views.py

```
@login_required
def user_page(request, username):

    user = get_object_or_404(User, username=username)

    ''' Form in the left-menu to create a new subject '''
    if 'subject-create-b' in request.POST:
        subject_form = SubjectCreationForm(request.POST)
        if subject_form.is_valid():
            subject = Subjects.objects.get_or_create(name = subject_form.data['name'],
                                                     user = user)
            return HttpResponseRedirect('.') # redirect to the same page
                                             # later have to be substituted with AJAX
    else:
        subject_form = SubjectCreationForm()

    # Filter Subjects table by currently logged in user
    subjects = Subjects.objects.filter(user__exact = user)

    return render_to_response('user_page.html',
                              {'subject_creation_form': subject_form,
                               'subjects': subjects,
                               'user': request.user,
                              },
                              context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

So my question is basically how can I do this?

Do I need to add new form and than put it right after the "

{{ subject.name }}". If yes, how do I know that this particular box have to delete this particular data object?

Or do I need to add some new column to mymodels, and than if check box is checked - switch this column to true and than in views delete all rows that have true in new column.

Or may be you can suggest some better techique. 
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to list the code for the form.

You can use MultipleChoiceField with 'choices' to be your queryset and use the CheckboxSelectMultiple widget to list the courses with checkboxes. From the form you can then get the courses that you want to delete.